# Subtract two Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes that I have read from csv files:

```
tmp1=pandas.read_csv(pathDataset1, parse_dates = [0],index_col=0, date_parser=parser)
tmp2=pandas.read_csv(pathDataset2, parse_dates = [0],index_col=0, date_parser=parser)
print tmp1 
    #index     #A
1.296518e+12  443
1.298938e+12  433
1.301616e+12  463
1.304208e+12  483
1.306886e+12  433
1.309478e+12  413
1.312157e+12  403

print tmp2
     #index    #A
1.298938e+12  403
1.301616e+12  483
```

And i want to get the difference between my two dataframes on my A column so i can get as an output something like this :

```
1.298938e+12   30
1.301616e+12  -20
```

I have managed to get this result with numpy.substract but that's only if those two arrays tmp1.values and tmp2.values are in the same shape and that's not always the case for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmp1.subtract(tmp2)` works even if the shape of the two DataFrames is different:

```
tmp1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1296518000000.0: 443, 1298938000000.0: 433,
                           1301616000000.0: 463, 1304208000000.0: 483,
                           1306886000000.0: 433, 1309478000000.0: 413,
                           1312157000000.0: 403}})
tmp2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1298938000000.0: 403, 1301616000000.0: 483}})
print(tmp1.subtract(tmp2).dropna())
```

yields

```
               A
index           
1.298938e+12  30
1.301616e+12 -20
```

Comment: that's exactly what i want but when i do use pandas method read csv it doses not work i get an empty dataframe as a result

Comment: I have managed to solve this little error i was missing header=none because it's not exactly a csv file. Anyway thank you your answer works for me !